# Unable to make view completely GONE after using TranslateAnimation

Tags: android

I had used `TranslateAnimation` and slide up and down a view.

However, I realize, even though after I slide down the view, and use `View.GONE` in its visibility, the view still able to receive touch event.

You can produce the same problem, by clicking on the button to make the orange color view disappear from the bottom of the screen. Then, when you click on the bottom of the screen, you will realize touch event of the custom view is still being triggered.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int color = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_light);
        // construct the RelativeLayout
        final RelativeLayout customView = new RelativeLayout(this) {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                this.setPressed(true);
                Log.i("CHEOK", "OH NO! TOUCH!!!!");
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };
        customView.setBackgroundColor(color);

        final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout); 
        frameLayout.addView(customView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100, Gravity.BOTTOM));
        customView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        Button button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (customView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                    // Slide up!
                    TranslateAnimation anim=new TranslateAnimation(0,0,100,0);
                    anim.setFillAfter(true);
                    anim.setDuration(200);

                    Log.i("CHEOK", "VISIBLE!!!");
                    customView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);         
                    customView.setAnimation(anim);   
                    customView.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    // Slide down!
                    TranslateAnimation anim=new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,100);
                    anim.setFillAfter(true);
                    anim.setDuration(200);            

                    // HELPME : Not sure why, after I hide the view by sliding it down,
                    // making it View.GONE and setEnabled(false), it still able to 
                    // receive touch event.
                    Log.i("CHEOK", "GONE!!!");
                    customView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    customView.setAnimation(anim);
                    customView.setEnabled(false);
                }

            }

        });
    }

}
```

The complete source code to demonstrate this problem can be found here :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1101dm885fn5hzq/animator_bug.zip

**How can I make my custom view not to receive touch event, after I had slide it down?**

Comment: Try putting `customView.setEnabled(false)` before `customView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not clear to me why you are using `setAnimation()` instead of `startAnimation()` as it does not appear that you have set a start time on your animations.

On another note, I have found that setting a view to GONE while it has an associated animation does not make it truly "GONE."  Instead, you must first get rid of the animation using `clearAnimation()`.

So, something like this instead:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (customView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
        // Slide up!
        TranslateAnimation anim=new TranslateAnimation(0,0,100,0);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        anim.setDuration(200);

        customView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);         
        customView.setEnabled(true);
        customView.startAnimation(anim);   
    } else {
        // Slide down!
        TranslateAnimation anim=new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,100);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        anim.setDuration(200);
        anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                customView.clearAnimation();
                customView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                customView.setEnabled(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // nothing to do
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // nothing to do
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't recall, but you may have to `post()` the contents of `onAnimationEnd()` instead of running the code immediately for it to take effect properly.

Comment: Thanks! Do we have to use post technique too for sliding up? Do you think having to use `clearAnimation` to make it completely GONE is a normal behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure if using `clearAnimation` for this purpose is "correct" behavior, it is just what I have found is necessary.  All of this aside, if your minimum supported platform is API 11 (Honeycomb) or newer, I would strongly recommend that you consider using the new `Animator` framework instead of `Animation`.  It is a much better framework and doesn't have these weird issues.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to support Gingerbread still as it is still quite popular. Had you tried http://nineoldandroids.com/ ? For my case, is ValueAnimator suitable replacement for TranslateAnimation ?

Comment: Yes, I use NineOldAndroids.  But, that doesn't get away from the `clearAnimation` problem, since NOA is just using the old Animation stuff under the hood.