# Scroll View in Android shows up when I scroll it

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a Scroll-view layout, which is, say my main menu, when user clicks on an item I want to make my menu disappear, and show the contents that user wants!
everything works fine, I use this code:

```
mainMenulay.setVisibility(View.Gone);
```

but, when I touch the screen, and swipe the screen (like scrolling when it was actually visible), where the main menu was located, the scroll-View show up in an unwanted buggy way !
its not functional, but it shows up !

I have fixed this issue with Z Order and defined a background and have brought it in front of the Main Menu and it wont show up, but I'm curious to know what's wrong, how to avoid it ?!

If you have questions about How I defined the Scroll-View, well. it looks like this:

```
   <ScrollView
       android:id="@+id/main_menu_lay"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:visibility="visible" >
```

Thanks in Advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen other people with the same problem, but only when an animation i used to hide the view.

[android View with View.GONE still receives onTouch and onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728908/android-view-with-view-gone-still-receives-ontouch-and-onclick)

and

[Unable to make view completely GONE after using TranslateAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087913/unable-to-make-view-completely-gone-after-using-translateanimation)

Probably, you can take a look at

```
View.setClickable();
```

and

```
ViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()
```

Comment: Yes I was using animation, but not translate for the menu, any how, I fixed it with Z Order, but I was wondering, is it really a bug ?!

Comment: actually, i didnt find any documentation explaining that a gone view wont receive touch events, and somehow i read that the receive it but are not meant to process them, weird thing, but i wasent able to find that reference now. Anyways an ScrollView and a FrameView and a ViewGroup has complex behavior, so its hard to say what is a bug, and what is a expeted but  weakly documented feature, or this kind of thing: http://globalnerdy.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/bug_vs_feature.gif

Comment: I guess you're right, it might be there for some overriding and extending, and all those objective stuffs :D
but the problem really is, It shows in very unpleasing way :/
anyway, thank for your time :)

Comment: anyways, as soon as i have the time, i will try to reproduce this and debug it with the android sources, so i can see what is actually happening behind the scene. Because this is an intriguing thing