# FloatingActionButton setVisibility() not working

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-design, android-design-library

I can't hide my `FloatingActionButton`. Here is my code:

XML:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>

    <AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/appbar">

        <CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <ImageView/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />

        </CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </AppBarLayout>

    <NestedScrollView />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

And I'm calling:

```
fab.clearAnimation();
fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I'm trying to hide the FAB, but it seems that `setVisibility` + `clearAnimation` does not work if the FAB is in a `CoordinatorLayout`.

Even if I call `fab.clearAnimation`, the animation is still triggered. Can anyone help me?

Comment: @Clairvoyant fab is FloatingActionButton..

Comment: try to add fab.invalidate(), under setVisibility.  Or switch the clearAnimation and setVisibility.

Comment: Are you using `@+id` as hardartcore has edited your question

Comment: @Clairvoyant I just forget to add `@+id/fab` in xml in my question

Comment: I think you should refer to :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087913/unable-to-make-view-completely-gone-after-using-translateanimation?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your issue is the animation, you could try invalidating the FAB `Behavior`. As for the visibility, you should null the anchor you have set in your layout:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
p.setBehavior(null); //should disable default animations
p.setAnchorId(View.NO_ID); //should let you set visibility
fab.setLayoutParams(p);
fab.setVisibility(View.GONE); // View.INVISIBLE might also be worth trying


//to bring things back to normal state
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
p.setBehavior(new FloatingActionButton.Behavior());
p.setAnchorId(R.id.appbar);
fab.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Comment: Does it work for you? I've try it, but it do not work... The FAB is still visible, and the animation still trigger...

Comment: What is triggering the animation? Do you mean that calling setVisibility(GONE) is triggering an animation, or it is just a workaround you tried to avoid the animation?

Comment: Edited my answer to also remove the `anchor` attribute.

Comment: The animation is the FAB can show/dismiss when scrolling. In fact, I don't care the animation. What I want is setting visibility of FAB programmatically.

Comment: And still nothing happens if you use the first four lines of my code?

Comment: First four lines disable some functionality that might let you hide() the FAB. The last four lines just bring things back to normal state - you should not use them if you don't need. Try using only the "before" section.

Comment: I've try it, the result is that the FAB only on the top left corner, it is still visible , but the animation gone.

Comment: I have experienced similar behavior in the past. Seems that CoordinatorLayout is not happy about setting visibility. You might try View.INVISIBLE rather than View.GONE , but I'm not sure it will work.

Comment: You are right. After testing, I found that it `fab.setVisibility` only works when setting the anchorId to null. I think you'd better add `fab.setVisibility` to your answer.

Comment: I faced same issue and your answer fixed it. thank you

Answer (score 49):

Use show and hide methods to show and hide the Floating Action Button

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

// To show the Floating Action Button
fab.show();

// To hide the Floating Action Button
fab.hide();
```

Comment: Unlike `fab.setVisibility()`, `fab.show()` and `fab.hide()` invoke animations. So if, for example, you are wanting to start a new activity after hiding the fab, you should use `fab.addOnHideAnimationListener(animatorListener)` and start your next activity from animatorListener's `onAnimationEnd()` callback. NB - you should call `fab.addOnHideAnimationListener()` *before* you call `fab.hide()`. If you don't follow these steps, you may not get a smooth hiding animation.

Answer (score 18):

For `FloatingActionButton` the `setVisibility()` method will give you an error while building with the latest `Gradle 6.x` and `build-tool 28.x.x` and is not encouraged any more. **Instead, use:**

```
fab.hide()    // fab.setVisibility(View.GONE)
fab.show()    // fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

> **Note:** Succesfully tested on `Android Studio 3.4.1`, `Gradle 6.0` and
>   `build-tool 28.0.1`

Comment: Rather than create a new (but very similar) answer, it may be more appropriate to add this information as a comment to mstoic's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53770108/1617737

Comment: I addition to him, I also added the reason why setVisibility() is not working.

Comment: Yes, I know. :-) But I think it would be more appropriate add that information as comments as your code (the actual solution) is identical to his.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into exactly the same issue. It would seem that Google's Android team doesn't want you to have control of the visibility when the FloatingActionButton is anchored to an AppBarLayout, as discussed in this issue - [FloatingActionButton Ignores View Visibility](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175331)

It looks like a viable fix is wrapping the FAB in a FrameLayout and setting the visibility on the wrapper instead, like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fab_container"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/fab_icon"/>

</android.support.design.widget.FrameLayout>
```

You may however wish to consider whether this is the ideal behaviour. Google advocates recommend that the FAB be visible as soon as the screen is created. If you're hiding it for longer than required to animate it in, consider showing a disabled state instead.

Answer (score 2):

you can disable it and make it semitransparent like this

```
fab.setEnabled(false);
fab.setClickable(false);
fab.setAlpha(0.3f);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FloatingActionButton layers = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.layers);
layers.hide();
```

It works for me, `setVisibility` doesn't work for `FloatingActionButton` as it belongs to another `viewGroup` that doesn't have `setVisibility` method.